# PowerShell Export-CSV to dropbox/online

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise, powershell-4.0

I am doing some tests and trying trying to export-csv the information to dropbox, i can do it via my desktop dropbox, but i need to do it via the web address. Does anyone know how to do it.

I need to do it via web address and not via dropbox on desptop, because there will be more people using this script and it will be a headache to make a hardcoded script when the others have different computer names and dropbox sits on C drive. In short, it will only work if i can actually export-csv to the dropbox web address.

Hope someone can help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox has an API you can use for stuff like this.
see https://www.dropbox.com/developers for the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible

You will need to create a Dropbox API key

Dropbox uses a RESTful API which you can use to upload files with, and Powershell has the Invoke-RestMethod.

unfortunately I cannot test because of the corporate firewall I am behind, but lots of examples on the net for using both of the techniques mentioned